# Set default SDK version on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-manager

I've got Android Studio 3, Gradle - 3.3 and Android SDK - 23 (Marshmallow - 6.0).
The following screenshot shows my Android Studio SDK configuration:
[image]

The problem is that every time when I create a new project the Gradle file is set to compile version 26. The next screenshot shows that:

[image]

How can I set the default value for compileSdkVersion to be 23?

Answer (score 0):

In sdk manager do following,

SDKManager>Android SDK> deselect API level  26 (and any sdk versions higher than API level 23 ) in SDK Manager and select API level 23

Answer (score 0):

You can change default SDK in Project Structure > Modules > Default Config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guNmC.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).